# iOS Youku play video with password failed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I try to play youku video with YKMediaPlayerSDK on iOS app. Passing password as parameter will show the password is wrong. This video and password works fine in our android version app.
Thanks for helping.

```
NSString *passwordAndClientID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", _youkuPW, _VideoId];
NSLog(@"clientIDAndPassword: %@", passwordAndClientID);
NSString *md5 = [self md5:passwordAndClientID];
NSLog(@"md5: %@", md5);
[_cloudPlayer playVid:_VideoId quality:_itemQuality language:@"default" password:passwordAndClientID from:0];
```

MD5 method

```
- (NSString *) md5:(NSString *) input {
const char *cStr = [input UTF8String];
unsigned char digest[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5( cStr, (CC_LONG)strlen(cStr), digest ); // This is the md5 call

NSMutableString *output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

for(int i = 0; i < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

return  [output copy];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like a bug in there SDK, we turn off password to solve it!

Comment: Could you add more detail about the bug? Any reference?